# Unable to reboot Sony Xperia XA in recovery mode

Tags: rooting, recovery-mode, sony-xperia

In order to root a `Sony Xperia XA` phone I followed the steps described [here](http://www.android.gs/root-sony-xperia-xa-ultra/), until the step to reboot the device in recovery mode. Using an Ubuntu computer and the phone connected by USB, I ran the following command:

```
sudo adb reboot recovery
```

after I copied the recovery image to the phone as described on the page linked above.

However, the phone rebooted normally and not in recovery mode. There was no option to load the root file to flash the device.

Is there any other way to reboot the device in recovery mode?

Comment: The site you linked to looks to be another one that just fits devices into a "generic" guide, which won't always work. Go look around in [XDA](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-xa) instead.

Comment: Many Sony Xperia don't have a recovery. You need to unlock the bootloader first then you'll be able to root.

Comment: Which Android version is your device?

Comment: Follow this guide: https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-xa/how-to/f31xx-how-to-root-xperia-xa-noob-t3430170

Comment: @esQmo_  Following this guide creates an error `Unable to mount storage`. See here: https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/182543/how-to-fix-unable-to-mount-storage-error-while-trying-to-root-xperia-phone