# How to fix "Unable to mount storage" error while trying to root xperia phone?

Tags: rooting, installation, sony-xperia

In order to root a `Sony Xperia XA` phone (using an Ubuntu computer and USB connection) I follow the steps described [here](https://forum.xda-developers.com/xperia-xa/how-to/f31xx-how-to-root-xperia-xa-noob-t3430170) until step 12. First, I am not able to select `Micro SDCard`. But I am able to copy the zip file to the internal storage of the phone. But when I try to install it (step 13), the process soon stops because of an error displayed on the phone:

```
Unable to mount storage
```

How to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

**Addendum:** I managed to copy the zip file to an SD card and to start the installation from there. No error occurs, but no installation either; the phone is still not rooted...

Comment: Is your phone encrypted or has any locking abilities?

Comment: How to find this out?

Comment: In settings: 1. developer settings >OEM restriction 2. securtiy>if device encryption is greyed out the device is encrypted

Comment: OEM unlock is enabled and phone seems to be encrypted (Option `Encrypt phone` says: `Encrypted`). Will a factory reset remove the encryption?

Comment: A factory reset will remove the encryption only if your device is on KitKat or older Android, on the latest Android versions starting from Lollipop, Encryption is forced just after Factory reset or Firmware Upgrade.

Comment: You should go to mount menu and check all the boxes you, thengo to wipe to erase data partition successfully (you should be to be able to Format data partition before skipping to step 13), then reboot the device in TWRP again and again mount all partitions including OTG/ External Storage / SD Card whatever the device you are using to store SuperUser.zip and continue your mission.